# Copy to computer from Google Lens application in Android to Macbook doesn't copied at all

Tags: macbook-pro, android

Using Google Lens in my Android smartphone and when select text and choose copy to computer option and select the macbook, it connected and show message in mobile that text successfully copied and ready to paste but in Macbook when I click **command + v** to paste in vs code (or even in notes), it copies the current clipboard value but not the google lens selected text.

macOS Sonoma 14.2.1
Android v 13

Same thing works when I select the desktop (which is windows 11) but not in macOS.

What could be the issue? Do I make any changes in macOS settings or Google lens giving wrong information at all when its macOS.